# Bind Single ResultSet to multiple class using Dapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have multiple classes which I use in different partial pages. I use Dapper for SQL Connection. From DB I get single result set with all properties.

How can I bind data to multiple class? Is there any chances to get this work? or I need to create a single class with all properties?

My models:

```
public class Class1{
     public int prop1 {get;set;}
     public int prop2 {get;set;}
}

public class Class2{
     public int prop3 {get;set;}
     public int prop4 {get;set;}
}
public class Class3{
     public int prop5 {get;set;}
     public int prop6 {get;set;}
}
```

ResultSet from DB:

```
PrimarykeyCol  prop1 prop2  prop3  prop4  prop5  prop6
```

Comment: [Here](https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/19163856/chaining-multiple-classes-with-dapper) is an example of using Dapper's Multimap Query with SplitOn Argument specified. It appears to be similar to what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly there is no relation between the three classes. Normally multimapping includes relations. For the multi-query to work you need a return type, so I would definitely declare a wrapper for the three classes like this:

```cs
public class Wrapper
{
    public Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
    public Class2 Class2 {get;set;}
    public Class3 Class3 {get;set;}
}

var resultList = conn.Query<Class1, Class2, Class3, Wrapper>(query, 
                 (c1, c2, c3) => {
                     return new Wrapper {Class1=c1, Class2=c2, Class3=c3};
                 },
                 splitOn: "prop3,prop5"
                 ).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: What would be the approach if I am using StoredProcedure?